# When I deploy a JasperReport + web project to the Tomcat7, it cannot show the exported Html

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jasper-reports

I can run the project in the MyEclipse Tomcat correctly, you can see it from the image1.

The pie-chart:
[image]

But then I depoly the .war file to the Tomcat, I got nothing, showing in the image2.

[the failed show][2].

And the following is my code about the exort.

```
File reportFile = new File(this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("/report2.jasper"));
List<SatisfPieData> satisfPieDataList = satifyDao.querySatisfPieData(sql);
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(satisfPieDataList);        
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
try
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try
        {
            //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(reportFile.getPath());

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,dataSource);

            HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
            request.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);

            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            SimpleHtmlExporterOutput output = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out);
            output.setImageHandler(new WebHtmlResourceHandler("image?image={0}"));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(output);

            exporter.exportReport();
        }
        catch(JRException jre)
        {
            jre.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(out!= null)
            {
                try
                {
                    out.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then I debug the code in the Tomcat, and find There is a function that seems to be a problem.

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint =JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters,dataSource)
```

It seems there is a error, but I cannot catch it. The function does not seem to end or is being given.

The jasperPrint function does not seem to end:

[image]

Does anyone know the cause of the error? I would be grateful.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Does the application freeze on this method (*JasperFillManager.fillReport*)?

Comment: Yes, the functions, such as 'JRBeanCollectionDataSource', 'JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile', can run successfully. But the method (JasperFillManager.fillReport) appears to be frozen. And the program cannot run the next code, 'System.out.println("jasperPrint end")', no matter how long I have waited. By the way, the dataSource is just 3 lines. And the whole project can run successfully in the internal MyEclipse Tomcat, but run failed in the external Tomcat. It makes me confused. Thanks.@Alex K